# 'One such+noun' vs 'such a/an + noun'

Tags: sentence-structure, nouns, determiners

What's difference in meaning and usage of 'such a/an + noun' and 'One such + noun'?. For example:-

> 1. I have never seen **such an example** of government turning its back on illegal activity.”
> 2. Never before has food security been **such a focus** of global attention.
> 3. **One such study** published recently in the Journal of Affective Disorders found that those who slept fewer than seven hours a night on average had an 86 percent greater chance of developing depression
> 4. An upcoming European Court of Justice decision will settle **one such case**, which involves the European Commission arguing that Apple Inc. owes Ireland 13 billion euros and Apple and Ireland agreeing that no tax is owed.

Answer (score 2):

There's two different meanings of "such" used here, as described in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/such):

> **such** *adjective*
> ...
> **2 :** of the character, quality, or extent previously indicated or implied
> *in the past few years many such women have shifted to full-time jobs*
>
> **3 :** of so extreme a degree or quality
> *never heard such a hubbub*

The structure *[ "such" + noun phrase ]* can have meaning **2** or **3**, depending on the context. But the structure *[ "**one** such" + noun phrase ]* can only have meaning **2**, no matter the context.

In your first two sample sentences, "such" has meaning **3**. In your other two sentences, "such" has meaning **2**.

In your sample sentences 3 and 4, earlier in the context, a particular type of example/case was described, and the word "such" is referring back to that type, rather than repeating it. Here's a simple example where you can see the previous context:

> **Alice:** We've got lots of customers who are angry about yesterday's announcement.
> **Bob:** Yes, I have **one such customer** on the phone right now.

In this context, "such" means "*angry about yesterday's announcement*".

And to demonstrate that the structure without "one" can have both meanings, I'll use it in your sample sentences 3 and 4:

> 3a. **Such a study** published recently in the Journal of Affective Disorders found that...
> 4a. An upcoming European Court of Justice decision will settle **such a case**...

Answer (score 1):

**One such study/case** means 'a study/case of the kind that has just been described'.

In constructions like **I have never seen such a...** or **There has never been such a...**, the situation is an extreme example of its kind. For instance, food security is said to be *even more* a focus of attention than it has ever been before.

Comment: the question was about one such x versus such an x.

Comment: @Lambie - That's what I thought I was explaining. Gotube has explained it better.

Answer (score 0):

**one such study**: = one or a study of the same class, type or sort

Merriam Webster

: of the same class, type, or sort
other such clinics throughout the state

**such an example:**

means: an example of this type or sort